# locationServicesEnabled test passes when they are disabled in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I have location services disabled for my application in the settings panel.  I run a test in viewDidLoad in my view controller to see if they are enabled:

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
   //Do something now
}
```

This test always passes for some reason.  If I try and access location services I get a kCLErrorDenied error for the location manager.  What gives?

Am I using the wrong test?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The *locationServicesEnabled* class method only tests the global setting for Location Services.  AFAIK, there's no way to test if your app has explicitly been denied.  You'll have to wait for the location request to fail and use the CLLocationManagerDelegate method *locationManager:didFailWithError:* to do whatever you need.  E.g.:

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {

    NSString *errorString;
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    switch([error code]) {
        case kCLErrorDenied:
            //Access denied by user
            errorString = @"Access to Location Services denied by user";
            //Do something...
            break;
        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown:
            //Probably temporary...
            errorString = @"Location data unavailable";
            //Do something else...
            break;
        default:
            errorString = @"An unknown error has occurred";
            break;
        }
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

See the documentation on the CLError constants in the [CLLocationManager class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) for more options.

Comment: That makes sense then why it always returns true.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan,if locationServicesEnabled is false, then i have waited for long time, but delegate (locationManager:didFailWithError:) method is not called. what is the reason??

Answer (score 20):

iOS 4.2 now allows one to determine if location services have been denied through the CLLocationManager `+authorizationStatus` method.