# iOS: Can I disable the default alert pop-up with settings button when location services is turned off from settings

Tags: ios, gps, wifi, cllocationmanager

In my iOS application, I want to fetch the user's current location. Before fetching the location I am calling below method to check whether location services has been enabled from settings or not.

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
```

I want to show a customized error message to user if the settings is turned off. But before showing my alert itself, Apple is showing one pop-up like below.

[image]

My customer does not require the settings button here. Is there any way I can disable this system level pop-up. If not disable, can I hide the settings button from the alert? Please help in this. Thank You...

Comment: No there is no way to restrict system generated alert. And also there is no guarenty whether this alert display each time when you turn off location service from settings.

Comment: Can I customize it? Will it show up each time the location is turned off?

Comment: I guess you can't customize location service turn off system alert.

Comment: No,Its an standard alert and you can not customize it

Comment: Thanks.... If the user clicks the cancel button... then will it ask the same alert again ?

Answer (score 2):

You cann't do this. If you try to do this apple will reject your app. Check this [Doc1](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5009), [doc2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5467)

**Update** Read this topic [Location-Based Services](http://www.apple.com/privacy/)

Comment: So, if I click on cancel button instead of settings button in the alert and try to access the location once again... then what will happen?

Comment: You have to manually open setting app and click to `yes`. That means, user haven't interest to share his location and your app don't force user to share to his location. You have to think about this and you can manually check user authorization and switch to setting app from anywhere.

Comment: That is true.. But in this case I have to do it from 2nd time onwards. Isn't it? Because when the settings is disabled, iOS shows the pop-up for the first time. How to actually know that I have to show my customized alert now or handle it in other way?

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. Because iOS is handling the error condition for the first time, I do not have to show it for the first time. How do I know that this is not the first time.

Comment: I already told you, check `authorization status`. Check this method `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` this link too https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLAuthorizationStatus

Comment: Can you please show me the code snippet to handle this. In my case, if the location is turned off when trying to fetch location, this pop-up is coming. When I cancel the pop-up and again try to access location, then it is showing the same pop-up for second time. But, next time onwards there is no pop-up when I repeat this. How to handle this.

Comment: look Melih Mucuk's answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153074/checking-location-service-permission-on-ios. and see this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Answer (score 1):

> Location warnings are the requests made by apps (such as Camera,
>   Compass, and Maps as well as location-based third-party apps) to use
>   Location Services with those apps. An app will present a location
>   warning the first time it needs to access Location Services data.
>   Tapping OK will give that app permission to use Location Services as
>   needed. Tapping Don't Allow will prevent an app from accessing
>   Location Services data from then on.

You can't disable this location service alert. It is a system system generated one.