# Detecting whether location services are enabled for my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

I'm developping my first iOS app, and this uses the user's location.

I know that the device asks the user whether to enable location services for the app, but how do I know if the user has enable it or not?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
```

should be the answer
releated SO questions are:
[Checking for iOS Location Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318708/checking-for-ios-location-services)
[locationServicesEnabled test passes when they are disabled in viewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401757/locationservicesenabled-test-passes-when-they-are-disabled-in-viewdidload)

and yes, according to @albertamg suggestion, if you implement [CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate)

you will be notified if user deny access to Location Services when you're requesting it
see `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` and `locationManager:didFailWithError:` methods

Comment: Also, if the user denies access to location service data to the application, the `CLLocationManager` object reports a `kCLErrorDenied` error to its delegate during subsequent requests.