# check for locationServicesEnabled always returns YES, Irrespective of manual toggle switch to decide if location services are enabled

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

```
location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    location.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation ;
    location.distanceFilter = 10 ;
    location.delegate=self;



    locationEnabledBool = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];

    if (locationEnabledBool ==NO) {
        UIAlertView *locationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Service Disabled" 
                                                        message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [locationAlert show];
        [locationAlert release];

    }
    else
        [location startUpdatingLocation];
```

The value of `locationEnabledBool` is always `YES`, independent of whether or not location services are enabled. Can any body help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of

```
if (locationEnabledBool == NO) {
    //give error message
}
```

try

```
if ( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ==NO || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    //give error message
}
```

I found this on the link.

[Detecting whether location services are enabled for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221004/detecting-whether-location-services-are-enabled-for-my-app)

Comment: `if ( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
//give error message
}` a little typo in the first [ bracket ] and a && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing this code, you will need to make sure that you test it on a device, and not just using the iOS Simulator.

Also, I suggest that you double check in the Settings on that device to make sure that **Location Services**, on the first page of the settings, says **Off**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was running the code on device and checked that Location Services says OFF in settings. instead of     if (locationEnabledBool ==NO)                                     if (locationEnabledBool ==NO || ( [CLLocationManager  authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied))        worked for me.